# Ruby on Rails display image as checkboxes in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, paperclip

I'm having this trouble where I can't display my images as options to select for a form. I want to create an photo album and at the same time select photos to add to the album.

I tried "collection_check_boxes" but I can't get the existing images to display as options. And I haven't tried to create (save) it yet.

I have my associations.
I'm using Paperclip Gem for the image.

**Models**:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :album
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**Controller:**

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :new]

  def index
    @albums = current_user.albums
  end

  def new
    @photos = current_user.photos.all
    @album = Album.new
  end

  def create
    @album = albums.new(album_params)
    if @album.save
      redirect_to user_album_path(@album)
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def show
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  end

  def add_photo
  end

  private
    def album_params
      params.require(:album).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

**Views:**

```
 <%= form_for @album, url: user_albums_path do |f| %>
    <form>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :Name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>

      ####################Tried this but didn't work because the image isn't a text_method
      <div>
        <%= collection_check_boxes(:albums, :photo_ids, current_user.photos.all, :id, image_went_here) %>
      </div>
      ####################
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Create" %>
      </div>
    </form>

  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
collection_check_boxes(:albums, :photo_ids, 
                       current_user.photos.all, :id, :id) do |b|
    b.label(class: "check_box") {
      b.check_box(class: "check_box") + image_tag(b.object.image.url)
    }
end
```

Where `object` is given to the block representing the `Photo` in `current_user.photos.all`. You may need to change the `b.object.photo.url` reference to match your `Photo` model. See the examples of giving `collection_check_boxes` a block in the [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately I had problems displaying the image still. It keeps saying the object I used is undefined. I did solved it another way though.

Comment: Idk if it changed or not, but now you should use `b.object` instead of just `object`

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve it by creating a method in the Model to fill in the text_method argument.

View:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:albums, :photo_ids, @photos, :id, :myPhoto) %>
```

Model:

```
def myPhoto
   ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("#{image.url(:thumb)}")
end
```

The Model instanced method allowed me to insert image_tag in the collection_check_boxes.